# Merging data from multiple Google Sheets into one using script with array

Tags: merge, google-sheets

I have multiple projects that output daily data to their own Google spreadsheets. I would like to make one master sheet in which this data is captured. This is fairly easy to do using importrange, but the spreadsheet becomes very, very slow when a large quantity of data is imported like this, so I'm hoping to use a script to just copy and paste the data over.

I know how to do set up the script manually using the following code from another post:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "ID HERE";
var sourceWorksheetName = "SHEET NAME HERE";
var destinationSpreadsheetID = "ID HERE";
var destinationWorksheetName = "SHEET NAME HERE";

function importData() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
  toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues());
```

}

But ideally, I would like to make the list easy to expand using an array. I've set up an "import" table (see the figure below), so I would guess a for loop running through it would allow me to do this, but I'm not sure how.

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gElh.png)

I'd really appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I've managed to cobble the following together and it seems to work:

```
function importData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var keysSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Keys")
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test")
  var keys = keysSheet.getRange("B2:B50").getValues();
  var sheets = keysSheet.getRange("C2:C50").getValues();
  var ranges = keysSheet.getRange("D2:D50").getValues();
  var row, startcolumn = 1;

  for (row = 1; row < 50; row++) {

    if (keys[row-1] != '' && sheets[row-1] != '' && ranges[row-1] != '') {
      var sourceSpreadsheetID = keys[row-1];
      var sourceWorksheetName = sheets[row-1];
      var sourceDataRange = ranges[row-1];
      var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
      var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
      var thisData = thisWorksheet.getRange(sourceDataRange);  

      var toRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, startcolumn, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns());
      toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues());
      startcolumn = startcolumn + thisData.getNumColumns();
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure that this can be done more efficiently using arrays, a while loop (rather than a for loop), and a keys table range that updates automatically based on its size, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with my high school coding skills.

Hopefully what I've figured out so far will help someone else!